# Пояснение принципов динамического программирования

Tags: алгоритм, динамическое-программирование

Уже не раз спрашиваю про мое больное место - динамическое программирование. Подскажите, где оно описывается так, чтоб даже я его понял? Читал Кормена, Левитина, рылся в Интернете - ну не понимаю. Вернее, как - с запоминанием понял соразу. По крайней мере, смог закрыть книгу и спокойно повторить.

Но вот эти расстояния редактирования или там с рюкзаком - пока читаю, кажется, что понимаю. Закрываю книгу и пробую то же самое повторить - и все, голова пустая, никаких идей. По себе знаю - это значит, чято я ничего не понял.

Понимаю, что в ответе вы мне вряд ли сможете изложить так, чтоб я понял... но где написано так, чтоб даже до меня дошло? Что посоветуете почитать?

Минусуйте, закрывайте вопрос, только помогите справиься с этой темой. Какой-то тупик!

Comment: Приходите лучше в чат такие вещи обсуждать. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AawQnuYSY4Y&list=PLUfHxBkkFMScK6mOOWp5s6LgbzmtfwmYQ

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле, всё просто.

Динамическое программирование - это когда от задачи можно отколупать кусочек, в остатке получить похожую, но более простую задачу, решить её, потом к решению обратно прикрутить ранее отколупанный кусочек и получить уже общее решение.

Многие задачи динамического программирования решаются рекурсивно.

То есть, мы берём большую задачу, отколупываем от неё кусок, откладываем в сторону, а в остатке получаем задачу чуть-чуть попроще, но всё равно сложную. Тогда мы повторяем процедуру - отколупываем ещё один кусочек и получаем задачу ещё проще. Так мы можем отколупывать по кусочку и получать каждый раз всё более и более простую задачу, пока не получится настолько простая задача, что её решение тривиально.

Тогда мы в обратной последовательности прилепляем к решённой маленькой задаче по одному кусочку из тех, что мы ранее отложили. После каждого прилепления получаем задачу сложнее - но за счёт того, что она уже частично решена, получить полное решение на каждом шаге опять-таки тривиально.

Ну или на каждом шаге задача может расколупываться на несколько кусочков, и каждый кусочек либо решать отдельно (если он уже достаточно простой) либо колупать дальше (если он не достаточно простой).

Собственно, к этому и сводятся все рюкзаки и подобные задачи.

Comment: Да теорию и я рассказать могу... А как доходит дело до практики - всё :(

Comment: Нужна практика, чтобы концепция уложилась в голове. Попробуйте начать с совсем простых задач - наподобие вычисление числа Фиббоначи или факториала. Попробуйте разобрать их на бумаге по шагам.

Comment: Да вот в том-то и дело, что эти задачи я как раз понимаю отлично - мемоизация эта, все просто. А вот в обратном направлении... Вот нельзя ли как-то не страшную таблицу составлять для сравнения строк, а идти так же рекуррентно, сверху? Не подскажете, это возможно? Применить в вычислению расстояния редактирования мемоизацию?